# Overlapping faces in mirror modifier causing z-fighting

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

I am using the Mirror Modifier to try to make a cinder block mesh. It is composed of some curves converted to meshes and some manually assembled faces.

It appears to be having trouble with overlapping faces, although I cannot see a reason for that to be happening. I have tried extruding the face that is having the most problem and it fixes it a bit but not entirely. And I am really unsure about the inside lines on the inside of the mesh.

[image: AO black lines]
[image: front]
[image: back]

Comment: maken sure there is no mesh on the otherside of the mirror , also make sure you turn "clipping" on in the mirror modifier

Comment: Better to add a .blend file here. According to the color of the biggest face in 3rd image, I can see many faces overlapped there.

Comment: @X-27 This worked. I just selected all and removed doubles. It removed a face that was doubled, though I never created the face... so not sure why this happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix this by going into edit mode of your object, pressing A (select all), or only select the faces in question manually. Press W to open this menu
select remove doubles

[image]

you can change the distance of the vertices being merged together by using this input 
field after pressing remove doubles

[image]