# Object appears as orange points in object mode, but looks fine in edit mode

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view

I cant see my gas station building while in object mode.

Looks good in edit mode:

[image: looks good in edit mode]

But only dots are visible in object mode:

[image: can only see dots in object mode]

Comment: in edit mode try pressing `Alt` `H`.

Comment: Are there any modifiers on the object?

Comment: Didnt work...hmmm

Comment: yes, its mirrored

Comment: Is it possible you could upload the .blend?

Comment: Sure there you go :   http://dc411.gulfup.com/3hX85K.rar?gu=u5KHYnT4tGXnuiEQVigw6A&e=1437008746&n=66696c656e616d652a3d5554462d3827274655454c25323053544154494f4e2e726172

Comment: go to the materials tab and change the material from HALO to SURFACE

Answer (score 3):

Your object has a halo material assigned to it.

change it to surface.

[image]

[image]

(By the way you also have issues with overlapping surfaces causing z-fighting. Fix it by removing doubles. See this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21218/1853)