# Weird artifacts in my UV mapped texture

Tags: uv

Any ideas what's causing those chunks of geometric artifacts?  Argh.[image]

Comment: These may be overlapping faces of the model and so something like Z-fighting; or overlapping faces of the UV map. Try to `W` > *Remove Doubles* on the mesh and *UVs* > *Pack Islands* on UV map.

Comment: Would help if we could look at the .blend

Comment: Thank you. The blend file is here: http://www.aworkofmarc.com/1/New_Barrel.blend

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Remove doubles in the mesh

What happens in your mesh now is  Z-fighting. Notice the clipping while rotating view around the barrel:

[image]

While in Edit mode select all and press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*. It will delete ~800 double vertices.

After that you can split normals either by adding **Edge Split** modifier or activating *Auto Smooth* in Object Data tab.

Also see:

---

Overlapping faces:

[Cause of black artifacts in render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render)

[Overlapping faces in mirror modifier causing z-fighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21216/overlapping-faces-in-mirror-modifier-causing-z-fighting)

---

Edge Split modifier vs. Auto Smooth:

[How to smooth shade an object while retaining hard edges?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/734/how-to-smooth-shade-an-object-while-retaining-hard-edges)